# An attempt was made to access a file in a way forbidden by its file access permissions

Tags: node.js, error-handling, permissions, permission-denied, file-access

I am run my nodejs with node app.js, get following error:

```
 listen EACCES: permission denied 8080
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: -4092,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '8080;',
  port: -1
```

this means  (Permission denied): An attempt was made to access a file in a way forbidden by its file access permissions.

how to resolve problem?

Comment: Can you provide source code that produce this error ?
Also are you shure that port 8080 is not already in use ?

Comment: @Alaindeseine about your fist question I cannot determine which code produce error. And about seccond questin I get this error on every port I run not only 8080.